# openstreetmap nominatim slash in housenumber

Tags: python, html, get, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm trying to form a get request to nominatim for geocoding. The problem is that in my country (Russia) we have a lot of houses with / in their numbers.

Example:

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/52433785
```

I have tried different ways of escaping / from url encoding, but with no luck.

```
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=40/49, улица Ляпидевского, Москва&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=40\/49, улица Ляпидевского, Москва&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=40%2F49%2C%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

All of the above mentioned request return only street, not house number.

So, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `40/49, улица Лавочкина, Москва` at https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org returns the correct object and leads to this URL:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=40%2F49%2C+%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

Requesting XML format works, too:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=40%2F49%2C+%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&polygon_geojson=1
```